# Persist GColors on Pebble

Tags: persist, pebble-watch, persistent-storage

I have a watch face app where the user can change the colours of elements of the screen. These are stored in localstorage, so they take a little bit of time to initialize when the watch face is activated. I would like to store these three GColors on the Pebble itself, so they are applied instantly and without checking localstorage of the phone. Can anyone give me an example of how this is done easily?

According to the Storage API of Pebble, values can be stored as boolean, integer, string, or arbitrary data structure type. I'm quite unsure how to read and write these three GColors into the Pebbles memory, as I use Cloudpebble and Clay to handle the slow, but working, settings.

Answer (score 1):

Got a bit of help on reddit/r/pebbledeveloper and u/please_press_start.

When passing a value from Clay via Appmessage, in the inbox_received_callback function I do this to write the colour value to PERSISTCORNER that is #defined at the top of main.c (the colour is picked from a standard color picker in Clay mapped to MESSAGE_KEY_COLOUR):

```
 Tuple *colour_t = dict_find(iterator, MESSAGE_KEY_COLOUR);
  if(colour_t) {
    // colour is a GColor
    colour = GColorFromHEX(colour_t->value->int32);
    //write to persistent storage
    int corner_colour_HEX = colour_t->value->int32; 
    persist_write_int(PERSISTCORNER, corner_colour_HEX);
  }
```

I apply the colour settings in init()

```
if (persist_exists(PERSISTCORNER)) {
    int persistcorner = persist_read_int(PERSISTCORNER);
    backgroundColour = GColorFromHEX(persistbg);
}
```